# How can I setup nginx to serve virtualhosts with rails(unicorn/passenger) and php-fpm

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, php-fpm, unicorn

I would like to serve multiple sites on one instance.

I install nginx, php-fpm, and a rails app.  I use [sites like this to guide me](http://imperialwicket.com/aws-install-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-amazon-linux).

I configure php-fpm to listen to a local socket

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

I configure ngnix with multiple hosts:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
```

I have several site php conf files like `/etc/nginx/conf.d/site1.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name site1.com www.site1.com;

    root /var/www/site1;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/site1.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site1.com-error.log;

    location / { 
        index index.html index.php;
    }   
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index       index.php;
        include             fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param       PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }       
}
```

and rails site conf files like

```
upstream rails {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.com www.site2.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/site2.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site2.com-error.log;

    root /var/www/site2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass                       http://rails;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme    $scheme;
    }
}
```

I have a unicorn rails server running via `rails s -p 3000`

Yet, no sites come up for either `site1.com` or `site2.com`.  I can get to the rails site at `www.site2.com:3000`

What is wrong?  I've spent 2 days (nearly 30hr) trying many different blogs, SO / SF questions, etc.  Please share your insight or answer.

**edit 1:** No log entries are created when I try to visit either site.  It's like the requests never come in.

Comment: I don't see any error messages or log entries. What errors did you receive and what was logged?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the logs are empty for these requests. (there's only older stuff for upstream misconfigurations I had made before)

Comment: Because you didn't specify an [`error_log`](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#error_log) directive.

Comment: @quanta i did, I just thought I"d simplify the code in my question.  I've re-added it for 'certainty'

Comment: Append `debug` to the end of `error_log` line, try again and post the logs here.

Comment: @quanta in some regard this helped me, as it showed that the logs (even with debugging set very high) were still not showing any inbound traffic. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Always check your firewall / proxy / incoming ports.

Everything in the above config files works perfectly fine.  The problem was that port 80 wasn't open to inbound traffic.

Comment: I am running a rails application on free instance of EC2 with Nginx + Unicorn. When I try to access public url, I am getting 404. I verified that Nginx + Unicorn configuration is ok. Here is [security group rules](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Keet.png) which is selected for the instance. What else I have to check?

Comment: You should ask this as  new question, rather than posting a comment.  That's the site best practices. Thanks!